# How to make my game not lag in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

im creating a a model of the classic arcade game dig dug in netlogo. So I tried o create a level and have monsters moving 3 steps forward and 3 steps back constantly in their areas but when i try to play the game lags and becomes very slow. please help

```
to stalk
ask monsters
[
  fd 1 wait .1 
fd 1 wait .5
fd 1 wait .5
bk 1 wait .5
bk 1 wait .5
bk 1 wait .5
 ]

 end
```

i tried putting this code as a forever button but then the game becomes slow. how do i set the monsters to pace around constantly while the hero moves around in the game?

(plz review dig-dug if your not sure what it is]

Answer (score 2):

The lag is coming from the use of `wait`.

You should regulate the speed of your monsters by using `mod` with `ticks` or by having a 'speed' variable. Here's example code for the first approach:

```
; move monsters every 10th tick
to move-monsters
  if ticks mod 10 = 0 [ask monsters [fd 1]]
end
```

Comment: Now it is too fast. how should i make a speed variable?

Comment: Consider using the "Frame rate" setting (in the "Settings...") button. A lower number will slow the model down and prevent more than a desired number of ticks passing per second. Be sure you have "view updates" set to "tick-based" rather than "continuous".